# Modifying query to execute faster but still get the same result

Tags: mysql, optimization, row

I have this query here that is supposed to output my data like this:

```
  tstamp             |   a1    |   a2
2014-03-29 01:00:00  | 100.12  | 150.00
2014-03-29 01:15:00  | 104.12  | 350.00
2014-03-30 04:00:00  | 500.12  | 750.00
2014-03-31 04:15:00  | 504.12  | 700.00
```

this is the query i'm using:

```
select distinct t_stamp, 
(select value from table1 as table2 where path='a1' and table2.t_stamp=table1.t_stamp) as a1,
(select value from table1 as table2 where path='a2' and table2.t_stamp=table1.t_stamp) as a2
from table1
WHERE date(t_stamp) between = "2014-03-29" and "2014-03-30"
```

the problem i'm having is on my real database, i have at least 5-8k number of rows per path and this query is taking too long to run, too long tht i can't see if the value i'm getting is correct or not.
i thought i could use this cause i tested it first on sqlfiddle and got the result that i needed but when i tried it out on my real database
its just too long.

is there a way where i can modify this query and get the same result but just make it execute faster?

Also on my database, the timestamp is in unixcode and not in the readable format can't edit it even if i want to (not allowed).

here is the sqlfiddle that i used: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/889ff/1

Comment: why not just `JOIN (select`? that query is running each subquery the number of times you have a row in the table. if you join a select then you should only be doing it once then can filter with a where

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this runs faster.. [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/889ff/34)

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT t_stamp AS time_stamp,
    val_1, 
    val_2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    t_stamp AS t1_stamp,
    value AS val_1
  FROM table1 AS table2
  WHERE path='a1'
) AS a1 on a1.t1_stamp = t_stamp
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    t_stamp AS t2_stamp,
    value AS val_2
  FROM table1 AS table2
  WHERE path='a2'
) AS a2 on a2.t2_stamp = t_stamp
WHERE date(t_stamp) = "2014-03-29"
```

Comment: The query ran faster when i tried using just the first join. The  Query took 0.2630 sec and then i tried adding the other join and its taking a long time to execute the query.

Comment: i keep getting a syntax error even on the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/889ff/28

Comment: yea thats because you have to left join ON a condition.. I edited the answer and also updated the fiddle